# Can an HTTPS served SWF file request non-secure HTTP content?

Tags: flash, http, ssl, https, network-protocols

Is there a way to have a SWF do cross-protocol (is that the right term?) HTTP requests when it is hosted in an HTTPS environment (via SSL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify cross https/http communication in your crossdomain.xml - see for example: http://www.senocular.com/pub/adobe/crossdomain/policyfiles.html#allow-access-from-secure